# Use object destructuring (prefer destructure)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a lint warning for this but I'm not sure how to destructure it, or why something so generic would need to be destructured.

`const href = window.location.href;`

Comment: So you put the link error in your title?  Also, what are you using to do the linting?

Comment: I thought you may using `ESLint`

Comment: If you want to destructure it, you could type the following:

          const { href } = window.location;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lint given you warning because the same keyword is using for declaring a variable `href` and also same keyword is used for accessing an object value `window.location.href`. That's why lint gives you warning.

If you try with different variable name then warning will gone

```
const ref = window.location.href;
```

If you don't want to change a name then you can destructuring like below

```
const { href } = window.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is because you choose to assign a variable that shares a name with the property you are accessing.  In your case, you assigned it to `href` and you accessed the property `href` of `window.location`.

Any such `const foo = obj.foo;` pattern would seem to be a candidate for doing destructuring with:

```
const { foo } = obj;
```

In your specific case, it is suggesting:

```
const { href } = window.location;
```